# Template doesn't overwrite

Tags: python-3.x, django

I render a template and return it. Program seems to render template only once and then even though I change input arguments, it returns the first rendered template. The function named getNumber works properly and returns different data each time. So basically the problem is that template is always generated with "Solution: 0". If the initial data would be 0.1, the generated template would always contain "Solution 0.1".

My template:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <title>file uploader</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id='selectForm'>
        <input id='selectInput' type='file' name='files' multiple>
        <div>Files:</div>
        <table id='selectTable'></table>
    </form>
    
    <script>
        ...
    </script>
    <p> Solution: {{ solution }} </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Function that return HttpResponse in views.py resolving '/'  url:

```
def index(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        uploadFile1 = request.FILES['file1']
        uploadFile2 = request.FILES['file2']
        text1 = ''
        text2 = ''
        with open('file1', 'wb+') as file1:     
            text1 = uploadFile1.read()
        with open('file1', 'wb+') as file2:
            text2 = uploadFile2.read()      
        data = calcpy.views.getNumber(str(text1), str(text2))
        print(data['number'])

        template = loader.get_template('main.html')
        context = {'solution' : data['number']}
        template.render(context);
        return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
    
    template = loader.get_template('main.html')
    context = {'solution' : 0}
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

Code in settings.py responsible for templates. I suppose here is the mistake.

```
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)

TEMPLATES = [
    {
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': ['templates'],
    'APP_DIRS': True
    },
]

# Application definition
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'version',
    'current',
    'calcpy',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles'
)
```

I use django 1.9.5 and I can't really change the version.

Comment: Default request method for  form is GET and you do not specify it as POST but you check for POST in your view. So your code in the if ...="POST" is never executed

Comment: I added @require_http_methods(["GET", "POST"]) before def index(request) but it didn't help

Comment: The form in the html  is missing the method <form action="/" method="post"> because inside your def index() you only react on a "POST"

Comment: It didn't help either, actually I had specified the method within script tag before. Program seems to enter the if request.method == 'POST'. It executes print, but doesn't execute return. I changed the embedded return in return HttpResponse("test") and it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the ";"  after template.render(...):

```
template.render(context);
return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```